# VBA CountIf() loop / Countifs() loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, countif

I am new to VBA and have had some success reverse engineering VBA using the VBA Recorder. However I am having a problem creating a CountIfs() loop for all cells containing the value "TT" in EITHER an entire column OR a dynamic range of a single column (using .end(xldown) / .end(xlup))

I would post my code but honestly, I have found so many different 'answers' to this question that I have not been able to mold to my use case yet and I do not think I am very close with any individual methodology. (ultimately I need to expand this to be a CountIfS() based on other column values but one step at a time)...

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this simple code---

```
Sub vbaCountIF()
    Dim Rslt
    Rslt = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "TT")
    MsgBox Rslt
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a loop for `other column values` and pass them as criteria in place of `"TT"`

Comment: SWEET! it works. I was probably overthinking it from the start. If i wanted to add additional criteria what would the countifs syntax be?

Comment: @ReedTurgeon You should accpet answer (Tick as green) if it works for you. For more criteria you have to add `Range` and `Criteria` like `Rslt = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "TT", Range("B:B"), "Hello")`

Comment: thanks for the info on the expanded CountIfs() and I was unaware of the green arrow deal!